# Can I place limit orders (like limit, stoplimit, trailstop..) in bonds (treasury bonds, municipal and other types of bonds)?

Tags: bonds, limit-order, online-trading, treasury, order-execution

Can I place sell limit orders (like limit, stoplimit, trailstop..) in US bonds (treasury bonds, municipal and other types of bonds)? or it is only market orders?

Comment: Based on your prior questions, you are probably referring to US products/securities, but should [edit](https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/145770/edit) your post to clarify.

Comment: @Morrison Chang yes you're correct

Comment: @Morrison Chang my broker only allow me to sell the fixed-income products by calling him, not even a mkt order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, bonds trade OTC (over the counter), whereas stocks trade on an exchange. As a consequence, exchange-specific order types are irrelevant/unavailable since your broker will quote you a bid/ask price at which you can transact.

The specifics depend on your broker but as an example, I'm only able to specify limit price/limit yield when buying/selling bonds (market price is greyed out).